# Does not compile with a preprocessor value on the command-line

Tags: makefile, g++, c-preprocessor

Where am I going wrong; I want to define a preprocessor value on the command-line for g++ but it fails. Below is sample code that replicate my problem:

[edit] I'm using:
g++ (Debian 4.3.2-1.1) 4.3.2
GNU Make 3.81

test.h

```
#ifndef _test_h_
#define _test_h_

#include "iostream"

#if defined(MY_DEFINED_VALUE)
#if (MY_DEFINED_VALUE != 5)
#undef MY_DEFINED_VALUE
#define MY_DEFINED_VALUE 3
#endif //(MY_DEFINED_VALUE != 5)
#else //defined(MY_DEFINED_VALUE)
#error  Error - MY_DEFINED_VALUE is not defined
#endif //defined(MY_DEFINED_VALUE)

class test
{
public:
 int val;
 test() {}
 void show() { std::cout << "val = " << val << "\n"; }
};

#endif //_test_h_
```

test.cpp

```
 //#define MY_DEFINED_VALUE 5
 #include "test.h"

 int main()
 {
  test t;
  t.val = MY_DEFINED_VALUE;
  t.show();
  return 0;
 }
```

Makefile

```
#=====
CC = g++
LD = g++
USERDEFINES = -DMY_DEFINED_VALUE
CFLAGS = -Wall
LDFLAGS = 
RM = /bin/rm -f
SRCS = test.cpp
OBJS = test.o
PROG = test
#=====
$(PROG): $(OBJS)
 $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(PROG)
#=====
%.o: %.c
 $(CC) $(USERDEFINES) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
#=====
clean:
 $(RM) $(PROG) $(OBJS)
```

If I uncomment the `#define` in test.cpp, all is well (prints 5). If I comment it I get the `#error`.

Comment: Calling `g++ -DMY_DEFINED_VALUE x.cpp` directly works fine. (prints 3).

Comment: @KennyTM: That's what I do in the Makefile - would this mean my g++ compiler is corrupt (hard to believe).

Comment: Or may be your makefile is wrong. Have you tried doing `g++ -DMY_DEFINED_VALUE test.cpp` in command line directly?

Comment: @kennyTM: this is weird - works if I run it without the Makefile. So the problem becomes: what is wrong in the Makefile?

Comment: Try `make --debug=j` to see actual commands executed by `make`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in your Makefile.  The `%.o: %.c` rule doesn't match a .cpp file, so GNU Make's built-in `%.o: %.cpp` rule is being triggered instead.

If you change `%.o: %.c` to `%.o: %.cpp`, it'll run fine.

Comment: Aaaah.. ! now I feel so small and stupid! thanks. Pity that something so silly can cause so much frustration & waste so much time.

Comment: Yeah, little things like that are the most annoying.  It happens to the best of us.  The only reason I noticed it was I added an "echo" just before the call to $(CC), then was confused when the echo didn't show up in the output.

Comment: Upshot of it is: I now know a lot more about C++ preprocessor commands than I did before this little hiccup ;)